# How to get data.table in error message of stop() function?

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to feed small table in error message, but cant figure out how to do it.
Here is documentation of function https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.1/topics/stop

Example of code

```
err <- "Error"
WFSub <- data.table(a = "12",b = "63",c = "84", d ="42", e = "92")
# Stops execution of code and prints error message to console
stop(paste0(err,WFSub))
```

Desired result would be:
Error 
a  b  c  d  e 
12 63 84 42 92

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `capture.output`:

```
stop(paste(c(err, 
             capture.output(print(WFSub, row.names = FALSE))), 
           collapse = "\n"))
#Error: Error
#  a  b  c  d  e
# 12 63 84 42 92
```

Comment: Pretty looking monstrosity. But does what I wanted, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got it 95% of the way there

```
err <- "Error"
WFSub <- data.frame(a = "12",b = "63",c = "84", d ="42", e = "92")
# Stops execution of code and prints error message to console
stop(message = err, print(WFSub))
```

The only weirdness is it prints a string of 1s the length of the number of columns at the end of the error message (i.e. "Error11111"). I'll keep playing with it to see if I can fix that and update if I do.